# Azure B2C SignUp Policy with mandatory fields

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the Azure portal to create a SignUp policy.

[image]

But can't find a way to make certain fields mandatory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in the standard policy (i.e. without custom policies) by going in the Page UI Customization, and for each page, selecting whether you want attributes to be optional or required. This gives you the capability to make an attribute optional in one page (e.g. local account sign-up) but mandatory on another (e.g. social account sign-up).

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, not sure why I missed it! Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for exactly this in 2022! Where did it go?

Comment: I was looking for this too... If you select one of your `User flows` and then select `Page layouts`, under `User attributes` you can change the `Optional` flag

Answer (score 0):

I'm referring to [Randy Minder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163534/randy-minder) answer,

the comments <!-- Required claims --> and <!-- Optional claims --> ,

they don't seem to work, if placed only (?) inside the Technical Profile. Also those are not mentioned in the linked documentation.  So I was struggling, how to make a newly created extension_attribute not mandatory.

Then after "trial and error", i found this post: [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048627/add-restrictions-to-custom-policy-and-make-claim-optional-azure-b2c). Apparently, if you add a restriction pattern, the field becomes mandatory. That is implicit and not mentioned in the documentation. Also a default value doesn't change this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by making certain claims required or optional, as shown below.

[image]

You can learn more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom)

Comment: Am I right in thinking, I then import that policy file. Currently, the import button is disabled. I think I read somewhere that you need to pay extra for that functionality...do you know if that's true?

Comment: Ah, there's an option to upload a policy file in the Identity "Experience Framework PREVIEW". I'll try that.

Comment: The question is about the standard policies, not custom policies.

Answer (score -1):

This response is inaccurate and misleading - the Required / Optional in the example given are comments (and hence do not affect functionality) which refer to which fields are required / optional when writing the registration data to the underlying directory.