# Azure AD B2C: Make built-in user attributes mandatory on signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How do I make built-in user attributes mandatory during signup? Is it possible without using a custom policy?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746884/85443}), However, I couldn't find that UI in the current Azure portal UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found it under Azure AD B2C, User flows, my signup user flow, Page layouts (and click on Local account sign up page).

[image]